# Loading PDF into PDFReader causes InvalidPdfException: "Rebuild failed: - is not a valid number"

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i working with itextsharp a bit and have a running application.

But in a few cases, i have trouble with this Exception.

> iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: "Rebuild failed: - is not a valid number - System.FormatException

What is the the application doing, very easy. I search for all pdfs in a directory via `Directory.GetFiles`.

After that i make a foreach through the array and open the pdf via the `filestream` function.

The next step is, that i open the iTextsharp class PdfReader.

```
[...]
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@targetfolder + "\\", "*.pdf");

List<string> name_list = new List<string>();

// Display all files.
Console.WriteLine("--- Files: ---");
foreach (string name in array1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);                
    var file_2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);


///itextsharp
 var sr = new PdfReader(file_2);

[...]
```

And in some cases, i got this exception?! 
The pdf looks normal, no special settings or properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some PDF's are broken. For instance: each PDF has a cross-reference table at the end that stores the byte offset of each object. When someone manually alters a PDF file, that byte offset can get corrupted. In such a case, iText will try to rebuild the file, and fix the error. Unfortunately, some PDF's are broken beyond repair. For instance: I have seen PDF's with references to an object with object number -1. That is not a valid number for an object. Such a file can't be repaired by iText.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF to reproduce the issue. Without it we can indeed merely say that the PDF most likely is broken.

Comment: there we have the problem, i can't share it because of confidential issues. But well, i think...it is only one pdf in a  monthwich causes this problem, i think we will find a "consultant" solution ;)